# How to retrieve all active access tokens attached to a delegation from event listener context

Tags: javascript, curity

I am currently trying to do some operations in an event listener where I need all access tokens linked to a refresh token. Is it possible to retrieve these access tokens from the context or am I required to interact with the data source in the event listener?

EDIT: This is regarding the Curity Identity Server.

Answer (score 1):

Some related topics below - if you can provide more info about your use case we can perhaps provide further details:

**REVOKING TOKENS**

If you want to revoke all access tokens for a refresh token then you cannot do this via script procedures. You would need to write a small plugin to interact with the data source and delete the delegation.

**LISTENERS**

An example event listener is referenced in the below resources, though the use case is not around getting all access tokens in a refresh token:

- [Article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/cloudflare-split-tokens/)
- [Code](https://github.com/curityio/cloudflare-token-publisher/blob/master/src/main/java/io/curity/identityserver/plugin/events/listeners/AccessTokenIssuedListener.java)

**CACHING INTROSPECTION RESPONSES**

It is recommended to cache introspection responses, and this is commonly done in the reverse proxy, as in [this LUA plugin](https://github.com/curityio/lua-nginx-phantom-token-plugin/blob/main/plugin/phantom-token-plugin.lua#L151).

Perhaps the simplest option is to give the cache entries a short time to live, meaning they will be only be available for a short time after revocation. Requiring immediate clearing of cached tokens would require more work, but hopefully the above techniques will help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm investigating the possibility of reducing the load on Curity by caching the response from the introspection endpoint, and I'm using the hashed access tokens as keys. So I need to clear the entries with inactive access tokens after a revoked refresh token, so as not to serve from the cache when a token is invalid.